# WPF - TabControl - Prevent Selection Change

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, tabcontrol

It seems that the WPF `TabControl` doesn't support the ability to cancel a selection change, since there is no `SelectionChanging()` event, only a `SelectionChanged` event. Has anyone figured out a way to do this?

The only way I have found is to attach to the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown()` event on each `TabItem` and set `e.Handled` to `true` if I don't want that particular page selected. This seems to work but is clunky.

Comment: <a href="http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/how-to-prevent-a-tabitem-from-being-selected/">Here</a> you will find a nice way on how to do. I remember having looked at it some time ago and also liked it, but in the end, I have done it with a workaround. I haev had a an issues with this solution that forced me to use the workaround but I can't remember what it was.

Comment: Not only clunky, but the mouse isn't the only way for the user to change tabs.

Comment: Isn't that just switching back after the switch was already done? The controls in the left tab may already be gone then.

Comment: This was probably the issue :)

Comment: After reading other sites and investigating the Microsoft reference source code, I think it's plain impossible to prevent a tab item selection. No way. It can't be stopped. If you (I) need it, use a different control, or roll your own TabControl. I'll probably use a different UI concept.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way do do this using a style for a TabItem and then binding the Focusable property to a boolean that controls the behavior.  Getting a binding to the parent view model was a bit wonky but that could probably be improved.

This is nice because it avoids tricks with click events which may not get fired if the user uses the keyboard for example.

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable"  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.IsUpToDate}" />
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
             <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Group}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```