# WPF TabControl change TabItem with Command

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command

I have a WPF application and in the main window I have a `TabControl`.
I would like the `TabItems` to fire a `RelayCommand` that I have in my `ViewModel` when they get selected (different commands for each `TabItem`).
I don't want a `TabItem` to be selected for some conditions that are set in the commands `CanExecute` function.
Is this possible?

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you need is to: 1. Prevent some `TabItems` to be selected; based on some logic (in which case see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851315/wpf-tabcontrol-prevent-selection-change) 2._do something_ when a `TabItem` is selected (in which case I think you can simply handle `SelectionChanged` event)

Answer (score 4):

I think the right way to go here is not 'ICommand' but just a ViewModel property which will twoway bind to the TabControl.SelectedIndex (or SelectedItem) then you can take the decision in the ViewModel. This is better than defining a lot of commands specific to each TabItem

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding VMSelectedTabIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
//OR
<TabControl SelectedItem="{Binding VMSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```