# Selection changing event in WPF

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, selectionchanging

I am looking for a way to prevent a selection change in WPF items (the Tab control right now, but in the future this will need to be done for ListBoxes, ListViews and ComboBoxes).

I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851315/wpf-tabcontrol-prevent-selection-change) and attempted to use the same technique that was marked as the answer.

In that technique you retrieve the [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) for the tab control's items and handle the [CollectionView's CurrentChanging event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.currentchanging.aspx) to prevent the selection from occurring.

For some reason, the CurrentChanging event is never being fired in my code.

Here is my very simple user control that I am working with.
It has a tab control with 3 tabs.

(XAML)

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlWithTabs"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl">
       <TabItem Header="First Tab">Content for the first tab</TabItem>
       <TabItem Header="Second Tab">Content for the second tab</TabItem>
       <TabItem Header="Third Tab">Content for the third tab</TabItem>
     </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

In my VB.NET code for the user control, I am simply retrieving the CollectionView for the tab control's items and using the AddHandler method to watch for the event.

(VB.NET)

```
Public Class UserControlWithTabs
  Private WithEvents mainTabCollectionView As CollectionView
  Private Sub UserControlWithTabs_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    mainTabCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainTabControl.Items)
    AddHandler mainTabCollectionView.CurrentChanging, AddressOf MainTabControl_ItemSelecting
  End Sub

  Private Sub MainTabControl_ItemSelecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CurrentChangingEventArgs)

  End Sub
End Class
```

I put a break point on the MainTabControl_ItemSelecting method, but it is never hit.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

-Frinny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` to your `TabControl`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both the question and answer, i was able to do this in c#. 
So for anyone needing something like this with c# code-behind, here's how i did it:

```
    mytab.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true; 
    mytab.Items.CurrentChanging += new CurrentChangingEventHandler(Items_CurrentChanging); 

    private void Items_CurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsCancelable)
        {
            FrameworkElement elemfrom = ((ICollectionView)sender).CurrentItem as FrameworkElement;
            FrameworkElement elemto = mytab.SelectedItem as FrameworkElement; 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("tab is changing."); 
    }
```

Comment: Note that if you with to cancel the tab change, you have to also reset it in code as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4194548). I had to also manually set the new tab item on the TabControl if I did not cancel the event.